# Retrieve only internal _id with NEST ElasticClient

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I try to execute a search with NEST ElasticClient and getting only the _id of the hits.

Here is my Code:

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var searchResponse = client.Search<ElasticResult>(new SearchRequest {
         From = this.query.Page * 100,
         Size = 100,
         Source = new SourceFilter {
              Includes = "_id"
         },
         Query = new QueryStringQuery {
              Query = this.query.Querystring
         }
});

public class ElasticResult {
    public string _id;
}
```

But the _id of the Documents (ElasticResult-Objects) is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that you get the results(documents) but the _id is null ?

Comment: @LijuL: Yes, thats the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_id` is not part of the `_source` document, but part of the hit metadata for each hit in the hits array.

The most compact way to return just the `_id` fields would be with [using response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) which is exposed as `FilterPath` in NEST

```
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "documents";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .DefaultTypeName("_doc");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany<object>(new[] {
            new { Message = "hello" },
            new { Message = "world" }
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(new SearchRequest<object>
    {
        From = 0 * 100,
        Size = 100,
        FilterPath = new [] { "hits.hits._id" },
        Query = new QueryStringQuery
        {
            Query = ""
        }
    });

    foreach(var id in searchResponse.Hits.Select(h => h.Id))
    {
        // do something with the ids
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

The JSON response from Elasticsearch to the search request looks like

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "6gs8lmQB_8sm1yFaJDlq"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "6Qs8lmQB_8sm1yFaJDlq"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually do the search or just return the doc ids from ES?

Comment: @sramalingam24 it performs the actual search (although in this example, an empty `query_string` query will evaluate to a NEST conditionless query, so will be the same as no query clause).

Comment: @RussCam Once FilterPath is used the response no longer contains scrollId which is null. Is it possible to specify scrollId in the FilterPath? I tried "scrollId" and "scroll_id" but both did not work.